# Unable to boot ubuntu after installing windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10

I had ubuntu 17.1 and I installed windows 10 I tried everything but i can't boot ubuntu again.. Win and ubuntu are installed on separated disks if I unallocate all the memory from the win disk will iI be able to start ubuntu with no problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go install grub or other boot so you can choose between them
grub2 i suggest.
it happens because windows boot is not comfortable with other OSs , microsoft things , you know.

although this may help :
https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

Comment: i know you can't open ubuntu, you need to boot it in live mode